# Writing my own MIB - any references of how to do so?

Tags: snmp, mib

Mapping some OIDs to system commands is actually all I need
However, I could not find yet a resource which explain how to compose such thing.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are books about SNMP and MIBs, such as the [SNMP MIB Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981492207). If you want to learn by example, read some RFCs that define MIBs, such as the [Printer MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3805).

Answer (score 1):

The Bible of MIBs is considered to be [Understanding SNMP MIBs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134377087).  If you're a book sort of person, that's the recommended reading.  The RFCs for MIBS are well worth reading too ([RFC2578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578) through 79) but don't give you a great feel for the corner and "how to" cases.

Answer (score 1):

I read [SNMP MIB Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981492207). I was a novice of the matter and it lead me inside MIBs very easly. VERY WELL ORGANIZED. Suggested!
I also bought [Unserstanding SNMP MIBs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134377087), but I didn't read it. After a brief look seems to be very complete.

Good luck!